# How to interpret the output of logistic regression in Sci-Kit Learn as a polynomial?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

Unless I am mistaken, a logistic regression model is simply a polynomial (typically where terms are to the first degree), where each attribute is a variable, and there is a weight associated with each variable.

I have trained a logistic regression model in Sci-Kit Learn, and would like to view the polynomial that represents the model, but I am unsure how to.

For the sake of elaborating with an example, suppose I have a dataset *X* with 4 attributes, and the corresponding binary labels *y*. Then, using the code below

```
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', tol=0.0001, solver='lbfgs', max_iter=1000)

model = clf.fit(X, y)
```

I would like to see the equation that represents the model. In other words, [I want something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufqoJ.png), where the i'th alpha term is the weight to the i'th attribute of X, and beta is some constant.

I viewed the official [documentation here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), but did not see a way to do what I was hoping for. Are there any ideas on how I may get started doing what I want to do?

Comment: For your case, does `model.coef_` and `model.intercept_` provide what you are looking for?

Comment: As @rickhg12hs points out, please check the attributes `.coef_` and `.intercept_` in the documentation link, which provide exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments already pointed out, you can get the weights (or *coefficients* in `LogisticRegression`) and the bias term (or *intercept* in `LogisticRegression`) via the `coef_` and `intercept_` attributes respectively. Here are the descriptions for both from the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn-linear-model-logisticregression):

> **coef_: ndarray of shape (1, n_features) or (n_classes, n_features)**
> Coefficient of the features in the decision function.

> **intercept_: ndarray of shape (1,) or (n_classes,)**.
> Intercept (a.k.a. bias) added to the decision function.

Following your example, you could do something like this:

```py
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', tol=0.0001, solver='lbfgs', max_iter=1000)
clf.fit(X, y)

print(clf.coef_)
print(clf.intercept_)
```

The values in `coef_` correspond to the features, i.e. the ith value in `coef_` corresponds to the ith feature in your training data.

Comment: I see, I overlooked this! Thank you very much!